# What is wrong with my MySQL update query?

Tags: php, mysql, post, syntax

For some reason, I am getting this error when using my edit script.
I even tried filling in the `POST` values and executing via `PHPmyAdmin`. Here is the error I got:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop=1, sell=10, cash=10, law=7, boss=1 WHERE ID=11' at line 1
```

here is the query:

> UPDATE toondb SET name='$_POST[toonname]', tlaff=$_POST[tlaff], ttype=$_POST[ttype], toonup=$_POST[toonup], trap=$_POST[trap], lure=$_POST[lure], sound=$_POST[sound], throw=$_POST[throw], squirt=$_POST[squirt], drop=$_POST[drop], sell=$_POST[sell], cash=$_POST[cash], law=$_POST[law], boss=$_POST[boss] WHERE ID=$_POST[ID]

here is the one with the filled in values:

> UPDATE toondb SET name='ik', tlaff=137, ttype=2, toonup=1, trap=1, lure=1, sound=1, throw=1, squirt=1, drop=1, sell=10, cash=10, law=7, boss=1 WHERE ID=11

All of the columns are `INT` besides name.  Name is a `varchar`.

Comment: `drop` is a reserved word in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please roll-back your edit to return the question to it's original form.  You can comment on one of the answers if you like, but don't change it like this after receiving answers.  As it stands now, the answers are meaningless.  Finally, if you find answers useful, up-vote them.  And "accept" the best answer if it completely answered your question.

Comment: oh sorry..how do i roll back my edit?  i dont remember what it exactly said

Answer (score 3):

The word `drop` is a reserved keyword. Use backticks to escape it.

Like this:

```
UPDATE toondb SET name='ik', tlaff=137, ttype=2, toonup=1, trap=1, lure=1,
    sound=1, throw=1, squirt=1, `drop`=1, sell=10, cash=10, law=7, boss=1 WHERE ID=11
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in `drop`. `DROP` is a reserved word in MySQL so you need to encapsulate it in backticks

```
`drop` = 1
```

However, you have other issues on your statement as well. You are susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: that doesn't sound good..how can I fix it so i am less vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @alfredo Don't pass unfiltered user input ($_POST/$_GET) to your MySQL queries. Ideally you should be using prepared statements, either using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: is there a guide on how to do this?  or maybe you could show me?  i have never done that before, i just learned what i currently know over the past months

Comment: @alfredo If you click any of the links provided by me, you'll find documentation/sample code on how to use prepared statments. The link in my answer will show in many major languages, and the 2 in my last comment are PHP specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting you column names in backticks just in case you are using a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The already posted answers are correct (`DROP` is a reserved word); I just want to make a point that syntax like `$_POST[toonname]` is technically incorrect - non-numeric indexes are supposed to be quoted: `$_POST["toonname"]` or `$_POST['toonname']`. The syntax you're using only works because PHP supports something called "key casting" - as the doc warns, this probably won't always be supported, and it can produce unexpected results: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts